# Reload view controllers in tab bar

Tags: ios, swift4.2

I have Five tab bars in my IOS App and in one of the I have a `UITableView`. I want the tableview to reload each time I go to that tab. Any help on how I can go around it. I have realised that when i navigate between tab bars `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` do not get called.

Comment: You can use `NotificationCenter`.

Comment: `viewWillAppear` should be called. In contrast `viewDidLoad` is only called when the view is first created from the storyboard.
If `viewWillAppear` is not called this is probably some bug. If you post a sample project, I could check.
First place to look is to make sure the `Custom Class` is properly set in the storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way, and what I usually use for that case of yours (I have such case in my current/main production project), is to use `NotificationCenter`, doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter

For instance, the user add an item to his cart, and the other tabs should be informed about this. So the controller (or viewModel, if you use MVVM) in which the user added the an item from will post a Notification, like so:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .userDidAddToCart, object: nil)
```

And before that happens, in each `viewDidLoad()` of each tabs (controllers) have already subscribed to that notification name.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.userDidAddToCart), name: .userDidAddToCart, object: nil)
```

This will reload all the tableViews or other views needed in all of the tabs.

Another way you could try is via delegate, or perhaps your `UITabBarController` subclass will inform these tabs about the event.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Before adding tab view controller you must remove previously added view controller from container use this code :

```
if self.childViewControllers.count > 0{
    let viewControllers:[UIViewController] = self.childViewControllers
    for viewContoller in viewControllers{
          viewContoller.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
          viewContoller.view.removeFromSuperview()
          viewContoller.removeFromParentViewController()
    }
}
```

After that you can load view controller in container view :

```
let navigate = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourViewController") as! YourViewController
self.containerview.addSubview(navigate.view)
navigate.view.frame = self.containerview.bounds
self.addChildViewController(navigate)
navigate.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

I hope this helps!